# What/where is the multitasking screen on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

In here https://whatsappen.com/news/5465/many-complaints-whatsapp-notifications-ios-11-update-solution

It states:

> This behavior is fairly common among users because of the
>   misconception that apps that appear in the multitasking screen are
>   running in the background.

I know there is a multitasking screen on an iPad, however WhatsApp is not released for an iPad, it is intended for iPhone. So what do they mean by the multitasking screen on an iPhone?

It cannot be the list of running apps displayed by double clicking the home button because apps displayed there *are* in the background, though they may not necessarily be running.
Is this however they are actually referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the sentence just before it reads

> It’s indeed an iOS 11 bug. It is affecting users who habitually force close their app. This behavior is fairly common among users because of the misconception that apps that appear in the multitasking screen are running in the background.

So yes, they are referring to the list of apps you get when double clicking the home button. It might be easier to understand if you look at it as the list of most recently used apps, irregardless of state.

Comment: That is actually not correct. The apps shown there CAN be running in the background, but normally they're not. It is wrong to infer as they do that the apps displayed there are running in the background, but the reverse assumption that they're not running in the background (that you state) is also wrong.

Comment: @jksoegaard Rewritten to avoid the can of worms here :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is that list they're referring to. And they're right in saying that it is incorrect to assume that apps viewed there are actively running in the background.